# How to get the shared post id in Google Plus ios?

Tags: ios, google-plus

In my application i need to share the post on Google Plus.After successful post on google plus i need to get the shared post id.

How to get the shared post id in Google Plus ios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/protocol_g_p_p_share_delegate-p all you can see is if a share was successful or not. You can't get the post ID unless you do something like scan the user's stream and even then you will only be able to see the post if it was public.

Comment: The page now has the warning **`Google+ Sign-In is deprecated`**

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the options menu on the post you want the post ID of (an arrow will appear in the upper righ corner of the post when you mouse over the area)
2. Click "Link to Post"

The post id will appear in the URL that comes up in the link to the post